# Conjugate gradient method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~barannyk/Teaching/hw7_Math432.pdf

Can someone help with #2? This is NOT homework. This was a website for Fall 2011, but it is a very interesting question and I would greatly appreciate help

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is the problem you are facing? Give us some hints.

Comment: I really need help in starting it. Can you please provide a solution? Thanks

Comment: Do you know how CG works ?

Comment: I do, its a bunch of formulas. Can you please provide solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the CG algorithm, presented e.g. [here at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#Example_code_in_Matlab).

```
function [x] = conjgrad(A,b,x)
    r=b-A*x;
    p=r;
    rsold=r'*r;

    for i=1:10000000
        Ap=A*p;
        alpha=rsold/(p'*Ap);
        x=x+alpha*p;
        r=r-alpha*Ap;
        rsnew=r'*r;
        if sqrt(rsnew)<0.05 
            disp(i)          % Note: I added this to see the number of Iteration
            break;
        end
        p=r+rsnew/rsold*p;
        rsold=rsnew;
    end
end
```

We then have to set up our matrices as described in the pdf, lets also call it $A$.
We have $b$ as our right hande side and need a startvector $x$. For $x$ I simply took $x=rand(size(b))$, so just a random vector of the same size as $b$.
Running the code, we can see that it takes 7 Iteration.

For b) you should take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method#The_preconditioned_conjugate_gradient_method). You have to modify the code above. Then c) is just playing with your code. It would be nice if you provide Information on what you tried. Also instead of calling CG "a bunch of formulas" you could simply understand and apply these formulas.

Comment: Thanks, but I was interested in a hand computational solution. Can you please illustrate it for this case problem and work out a few by hand?

Comment: Above comment was for part a. For part b, can you also elaborate by hand. Thanks!!

Comment: Well you can simply do the code "by hand". Just move from line to line and see what you have to do.